# How to read the Spring framework source code?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have experience using spring and read books about it. However, when I try to read the open source code, I found that I don't know where to start and how to read it so as to understand it fully. Is there anything like class diagram or how to get to know an open source project like spring and understand the codes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise you to concentrate on one module at a time.

If your currently working on spring then I would suggest using your IDE or dependency management to download the module your working on and try and learn that.  That way you can step through the code using debugger and get a decent idea.

The Spring github sites are very helpful and are where the code is hosted - e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

The next step would be to start to have a look at the Gitter projects - https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot which is where most of the spring discussions happen.

I would strongly advise following Josh Long the spring developer advocate - user:607357 on here and easy to find on the web and twitter.

Hope this helps.